# Header line classicthesis in smaller layout

Tags: classicthesis

I use the classicthesis template by Andre Miede in Version 4.2. I just changed the page dimensions to fit a smaller layout like so:

```
\usepackage[ paperheight  =23.495cm,paperwidth   =15.557cm,
         layoutheight =22.861cm,layoutwidth  =15.24cm,
         layoutvoffset= 0.317cm,layouthoffset= 0.1585cm,
         textwidth=290pt,bottom=2cm,
         showcrop=true]{geometry}
```

everything works fine except the Header line on even pages. It doesnt line up with the text block:

[image]

wheras on uneven pages the positioning is right:

[image]

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @bananabombo When I insert your geometry package call into the original template, just after the call to classicthesis (v4.6), I don't get this - everything up there seems fine. Only two exceptions: your layoutheight of 22.9cm doesn't leave enough space on the bottom for the 'draft' mark, there's not enough space for the margin notes. Check if adding the `showframe` option to the call to `geometry` gives you any clue of what's happening.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip im working with Version 4.2 of classicthesis on overleaf which is provided via this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/docs?snip_uri=http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/theses/2/thesis_2_OL.zip). The Problem does not seem to occur in Version 4.6 of classicthesis. is there any way to move a Project from classicthesis 4.2 to 4.6 on overleaf? Or is there a way to fix the Problem in classicthesis 4.2?

Comment: @bananabombo Can you overwrite classicthesis.sty and classicthesis-config.tex in your overleaf directory? Just copy those and you'll have v4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only appeared in Version 4.2 of classicthesis. So i had to transfer my classicthesis project to a newer version like 4.6. I first copied the parts of the config-file i adapted to my needs. Then overwriting `classicthesis.sty` and `classicthesis-config.tex` as @PhilipPirrip suggested did the trick.